# Configuring and rotating logs for Apache lbmethod_heartbeat module

Tags: apache-2.4, redhat, logging, heartbeat

The problem I'm having is a log file growing and using all available disk space on the server. The server is RHEL on AWS EC2. The file causing problems is located in `/tmp/systemd-private-*-httpd.service-*/tmp/heartbeat.log`

The only module I see loaded that could be producing this log is `lbmethod_heartbeat`. I however do not see any configuration for the module or logs.

How can I configure the location this log is placed in and rotate the log? Why is it being saved in the `tmp` directory?

Comment: Have you looked at the log file to be sure it is what you think it is?

Comment: Yes, I've looked at it. That's the only module that's loaded with anything to do with heartbeat. Not sure why it is saved in tmp and hoping I can rotate is. If all else fails I can set up logrotate to rotate the file in tmp folder, but that doesn't sound like the best solution.